# Cut off threshold for a 3 class classification problem

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, roc, auc

I have built a random forest model for a 3 class(low, medium, high) classification problem.I want to obtain the optimal probability threshold value for the model.

Upon running this code, I am getting a error-

```
false_pos_rate, true_pos_rate, proba = metrics.roc_curve(y_test, predicted_proba[:, -1])
```

The error states -

```
ValueError: multiclass format is not supported
```

How do I go about arriving at an optimal probability decision threshold for three class problem ?

Answer (score 0):

in the official Sklean examples they use the `OneVsAll` approach to get the ROC for each class independently and get a threshold for each class.
go to this link for the code sample: [sklean examples](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html#plot-roc-curves-for-the-multilabel-problem)